# Retain keys with null values while writing JSON in spark

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a JSON file using spark. There are some keys that have `null` as value. These show up just fine in the `DataSet`, but when I write the file, the keys get dropped. How do I ensure they are retained?

code to write the file:

```
ddp.coalesce(20).write().mode("overwrite").json("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dedupe_employee");
```

part of JSON data from source:

```
"event_header": {
        "accept_language": null,
        "app_id": "App_ID",
        "app_name": null,
        "client_ip_address": "IP",
        "event_id": "ID",
        "event_timestamp": null,
        "offering_id": "Offering",
        "server_ip_address": "IP",
        "server_timestamp": 1492565987565,
        "topic_name": "Topic",
        "version": "1.0"
    }
```

Output:

```
"event_header": {
        "app_id": "App_ID",
        "client_ip_address": "IP",
        "event_id": "ID",
        "offering_id": "Offering",
        "server_ip_address": "IP",
        "server_timestamp": 1492565987565,
        "topic_name": "Topic",
        "version": "1.0"
    }
```

In the above example keys `accept_language`, `app_name` and `event_timestamp` have been dropped.

Comment: You can use the below answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75220469/12847919

Comment: A similar question and answer --
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75220469/12847919

Answer (score 9):

If you are on Spark 3, you can add

```
spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields false
```

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, spark does not provide any option to handle nulls. So following custom solution should work.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

case class EventHeader(accept_language:String,app_id:String,app_name:String,client_ip_address:String,event_id: String,event_timestamp:String,offering_id:String,server_ip_address:String,server_timestamp:Long,topic_name:String,version:String)

val ds = Seq(EventHeader(null,"App_ID",null,"IP","ID",null,"Offering","IP",1492565987565L,"Topic","1.0")).toDS()

val ds1 = ds.mapPartitions(records => {
val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
records.map(mapper.writeValueAsString(_))
})

ds1.coalesce(1).write.text("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dedupe_employee")
```

This will produce output as :

```
{"accept_language":null,"app_id":"App_ID","app_name":null,"client_ip_address":"IP","event_id":"ID","event_timestamp":null,"offering_id":"Offering","server_ip_address":"IP","server_timestamp":1492565987565,"topic_name":"Topic","version":"1.0"}
```

Comment: can you provide a solution like this in pyspark? Thanks

Comment: @vi_ral Pyspark solutions shown in bloodrotfc's or lzw's post. Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673241/10002593.

Answer (score 1):

To retain null values converting to JSON please set this config option.

```
spark = ( 
   SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")
   .config("spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields", "false")
).getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ignoreNullFields`](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26227) is an option to set when you want DataFrame converted to json file since Spark 3.

If you need Spark 2 (specifically PySpark 2.4.6), you can try converting DataFrame to rdd with Python dict format. And then call `pyspark.rdd.saveTextFile` to output json file to hdfs. The following example may help.

```
cols = ddp.columns
ddp_ = ddp.rdd
ddp_ = ddp_.map(lambda row: dict([(c, row[c]) for c in cols])
ddp_ = ddp.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(your_hdfs_file_path)
```

This should produce output file like,

```
{"accept_language": None, "app_id":"123", ...}
{"accept_language": None, "app_id":"456", ...}
```

What's more, if you want to replace Python `None` with JSON `null`, you will need to dump every dict into json.

```
ddp_ = ddp_.map(lambda row: json.dumps(row, ensure.ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3, and if you are using the class DataFrameWriter

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#json-java.lang.String-

(same applies for pyspark)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html

its json method has an option ignoreNullFields=None

where None means True.

So just set this option to false.

```
ddp.coalesce(20).write().mode("overwrite").option("ignoreNullFields", "false").json("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dedupe_employee")
```