# Spark save as JSON ignoring null values

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am getting JSON data from Kafka as an RDD.

```
{id:"A",amount:"100"}
{id:"B",amount:"NULL"}
```

Then, using Spark built in functions to create a DataFrame spark.read.json(rdd), which would give me

```
id|amount
 a|100
 b|NULL

schema:
  id:String
  amount:String
```

Then, I type cast the amount to Integer, then the NULL value is automatically converted to null. So, after type casting this how my data is looking like

```
id|amount
 a|100
 b|null
```

After few more transformations, I am converting these records again to JSON and writing to another Kafka. So, while I convert these records to JSON the null values are getting ignored.

```
{id:"a",amount:100}
{id:"b"}
```

Before, pushing to Kafka I am again typecasting the data to String Type. So, I need output as

```
{id:"a",amount:"100"}
{id:"b",amount:"NULL"}
```

Comment: why you cast to integer if you want the values as String ?

Comment: After casting to Integer, I am persisting it to a DB. Then Writing to another Kafka

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain keys with null values while writing JSON in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271612/retain-keys-with-null-values-while-writing-json-in-spark)

Comment: @hadooper the output I am expecting is NULL not null. Anyways i figured out the solution will post it soon.

Comment: @Venkata have you figured any solution, Thanks

Comment: @YashwanthKambala, I am doing the below operation, hope that helps.

dataFrame
      .select(dataFrame.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)):_*).na.fill("")

Comment: May I know How different is it from DS.na().fill(""), which applies on entire DS.