# aws glue dropping mostly null fields

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a dataframe df.  It has a couple columns that are mostly null.  I'm writing it to an s3 bucket using the code below.  I then crawl the s3 bucket to get the table schema in the datacatalog.  I'm finding when I crawl the data the fields that are mostly null get dropped.  I've checked the json that is output and I'm finding that some records have the field, and others don't.  Does anyone know what the issue might be?  I would like to include the fields even if they are mostly null.

Code:

```
# importing libraries

import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.functions  import date_format
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date,format_number,dayofmonth,hour,dayofyear,month,year,weekofyear,date_format,unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


# write to table
df.write.json('s3://path/table')
```

Comment: This behaviour is expected from Spark. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44283055/4326922

Comment: @bdcloud Thank you for getting back to me on this.  So spark will drop the fields when they're completely null?  The fields I'm working with are mostly null, but not completely.  One of the fields which has slightly less missing values than the other, shows up in the exported data.  Is there a null threshold in the write function that can be adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use AWS Glue write method instead of spark DF?

> glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options