# why spark to_json() not populating null values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can try in spark-shell

```
case class Employee(id: Int, name: String, department: String, salary: Option[Double])
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

case class Employee(id: Int, name: String, department: String, salary: Option[Double])
val data = List(Employee(1, "XYZ", "dep1", Some(1234.0)), Employee(0, null, "unknown", None)).toDS()
data.select($"id", to_json(struct($"id",$"name", $"department", $"salary")).as("json_data")).show(false)
```

return =>

```
|id |json_data                                                |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"id":1,"name":"XYZ","department":"dep1","salary":1234.0}|
|0  |{"id":0,"department":"unknown"}                          |
```

expecting =>

```
|id |json_data                                                   |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"id":1,"name":"XYZ","department":"dep1","salary":1234.0}   |
|0  |{"id":0,"name": null, "department":"unknown","salary":null} |
```

null fields(**name & salary**) also should be populated in resulting json. I don't want to use lit("null") to populate null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A feature was recently added to preserve null values when generating JSON, and should be available in the upcoming Spark 3.0 release. See [SPARK-29444](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29444) for details. In 3.0, you'll be able to control this via:

`data.select($"id", to_json(struct($"id",$"name", $"department", $"salary"), Map("ignoreNullFields" -> "false")).as("json_data")).show(false)`

AFAIK, there are no plans at present to add this to the 2.x branch.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie. but is there any way to hack in 2.x version?

Comment: You could add in the [relevant changes](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26098/files) yourself and then build from source, although this might not be practical if you're in any sort of managed Spark environment. Another option would be to sign up on their JIRA and propose backporting the change, maybe even creating your own pull request.

Answer (score 0):

For spark 3.0, you could use Map(ignoreNullFields" -> "false") as an option to to_json method.
For spark 2.0 and less, you can use the below implementation -

```
def convertIntoJsonWithNullValuesIncluded(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val colnms_n_vals = df.columns.flatMap { c => Array(lit(c), col(c)) }
    val jsonDf = df.withColumn("myMap", functions.map(colnms_n_vals: _*)).select(to_json(struct(col("myMap"))).alias("json"))
    val cutStringUdf = udf((x: String) => cutString(x))
    jsonDf.withColumn("value", cutStringUdf(col("json"))).drop("json")
  }
  def cutString(s: String): String = {
    s.substring(9, -2)
  }
```