# How to maintain all the keys having null values of a dataframe while writing it into JSON in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

code to write the file:
`df.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode("append").save("/user/hive/warehouse/cpevoiceassistanteventhistory")`

part of JSON data from source:

```
"event_header": {
        "accept_language": null,
        "app_id": "App_ID",
        "app_name": null,
        "client_ip_address": "IP",
        "event_id": "ID",
        "event_timestamp": null,
        "offering_id": "Offering",
        "server_ip_address": "IP",
        "server_timestamp": 1492565987565,
        "topic_name": "Topic",
        "version": "1.0"
    }
```

Output:

```
"event_header": {
        "app_id": "App_ID",
        "client_ip_address": "IP",
        "event_id": "ID",
        "offering_id": "Offering",
        "server_ip_address": "IP",
        "server_timestamp": 1492565987565,
        "topic_name": "Topic",
        "version": "1.0"
    }
```

In the above example keys accept_language, app_name and event_timestamp have been dropped.

[This the code in scala, I want to do the same in Pyspark, not getting any perfect solution. Please click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271612/retain-keys-with-null-values-while-writing-json-in-spark)

Comment: No, thats the solution in scala. I need solution in pyspark @CPak

Comment: My fault for not reading more closely

Comment: No problem at all, please help if any idea on the same.