# How to NOT SKIP null values in spark JSON?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jackson

I have a DF which I am trying to parse in a schema. But the class which is being used to create the schema is skipping if any value is null in the object.

Example:

```
case class Parent(
                           Version: Int,
                           Info: InfoInstance
                           )
```

And the nested class is as follows:

```
case class InfoInstance(
                          FName: String ,
                          SName: String,
                          ID: Double,
                          ErrorCode: Int
                        )
```

So if by any chance in InfoInstance, the Fname is null as value, it altogether skips the key, and comes back as

```
{ Sname: "abc", ID: 23123123, ErrorCode: 123 }
```

I would like it to return null if it's null.

```
    { FName: null, Sname: "abc", ID: 23123123, ErrorCode: 123 }
```

I am on spark 2.2 so I cannot use ignoreNullFields. I also tried using JSONInclude.Always, but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if you have a property that is a class, it's default value is null.  You can set most JSON serialisers to ignore or show those values PRECISELY because telling you that an object is null, is redundant.  If you didn't give it a value, of COURSE it is.  If it's not in the JSON, it gets it's default value in the object when you deserialise.  A smart serialiser would not bother serialising ints that are zero, for the same reason

I googled and it seems someone has answered this question in the past

[Retain keys with null values while writing JSON in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271612/retain-keys-with-null-values-while-writing-json-in-spark)

although, again, putting nulls in your JSON is redundant and adds no value.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've seen that answer, but it doesn't match my scenario, as I am mapping to an existing schema.

Comment: But the value is null even if it is not in your JSON.  it is null BY DEFAULT.

I linked to a code solution to add the null values if you want to see them there.......